How do I multiply two lists in bend?
I'm trying to wrap my head around the bend programming language and I am struggling to understand how I can iterate/fold over multiple datastructures together.
given two lists
l = [1,2,3,4]
k = [5,6,7,8]

I'd like to do something like this: I want to fold over the two datastructures together and create a new list with the products: [(1*5),(2*6),(3*7),(4*8)]
result = fold l,k
  case List/Cons,List/Cons:
     return l*k
  case List/Nil
     return 0

But this doesn't work as it's incorrect syntax. Can someone also link a reference of the language? The github repo only contains syntax.md but it's incomplete/inaccurate (list comprehensions aren't implemented yet,etc.)
